# Select and Edit upon creation of node.appendChild in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, edit

I'm very new to Extjs, Im currently working with a tree, where I can create a branch and then create sections. I would need help with editing function for my code.

createSection: function(button) {
var node = button.up('menu').node;

```
    if (node.data.leaf) {
        return false;
    }

    node.expand();

    var newSection = node.appendChild({
        name: 'New section ' + "(" + (node.childNodes.length +1) + ")" ,
        type: 'toc-by-system',
        leaf: false,
        id: uuid['v4'](),
        children: [],
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }
    });

    newSection.BeginEdit(),
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle it has option for both single click and double click to edit
[Dynamic tree cell editor](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3nmr)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I try to use your code inside a createSection function instead of an tbar. But i get error saying like getRootNode is not a function. Can it be because Im using older version of Sencha? im currently on 4.02 or something like that. 
Thanks again for taking time to help me out here :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the sample code, to add node programmatically on button click!

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
            root: {
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    id: 3,
                    text: 'detention'
                }, {
                    text: 'homework',
                    id: 5,
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [{
                        text: 'book report',
                        id: 7,
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        text: 'algebra',
                        id: 9,
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    text: 'buy lottery tickets',
                    id: 37,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            title: 'Simple Tree',
            itemId: 'menu',
            tbar: [{
                text: 'button',
                handler(button) {
                    var treeNode = button.up('#menu').getRootNode();
                    if (treeNode.data.leaf) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    treeNode.expand();
                    treeNode.appendChild({
                        text: 'New section ' + ((treeNode.childNodes.length) + 1),
                        type: 'toc-by-system',
                        leaf: false,
                        children: [],
                    });
                }
            }],
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            store: store,
            rootVisible: false,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
```

Comment: heres the image of how i want it to look like https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Untitled_228.png

 when I create new section, it should be ready to edit. Right now i have to double click on it in order to edit.